# Remove object from the image

Tags: image-processing

How to remove spider from "spider web"?

[image]

there is good example in documentation center

[image]

but how to make black marker of spider?

Comment: You will need the mask first. Do you have the mask?

Answer (score 12):

This is a fast and quite good way to create the mask of the spider:

```
i = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Lz0A.jpg"];
mask = Dilation[
  DeleteSmallComponents@ ColorNegate@ DeleteSmallComponents@
    MorphologicalBinarize[i, .25], 
  DiskMatrix[2]]
```

[image: spider_mask]

Then, you can use Inpaint with the generated mask:

```
Inpaint[i, mask]
```

[image: inpainted_web]

You will have to adjust the `MorphologicalBinarize` threshold value to achieve good results for other images.

Answer (score 2):

You should first generate the mask, then you can apply `Inpaint`. Following is a demo, it can be further enhanced.

```
flt = ColorNegate@MorphologicalBinarize[img, {0.4, 0.9}];
Inpaint[img, flt];
```

[image]